GCR push issue in GCP
I am using github action to build and push docker image in GCP container registry using below code.
      - name: Login to Docker
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.GCR_IMAGE_NAME }}:latest .
          docker push ${{ secrets.GCR_IMAGE_NAME }}:latest

But getting below error in "Login to Docker" step
***
/home/runner/work/_temp/3ca1e410-1327-4979-bcf4-197df8b88472.sh: line 2: type:: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

I have verified the SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY used has "Storage Admin" role.
What could be issue here?

you can use action from market place for docker login to gcr or any other container registry
Please refer this doc more information -
https://github.com/docker/login-action?tab=readme-ov-file#google-container-registry-gcr
example :
jobs:
  login:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    -
      name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
      id: auth
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
      with:
        token_format: access_token
        workload_identity_provider: <workload_identity_provider>
        service_account: <service_account>
    -
      name: Login to GCR
      uses: docker/login-action@v3
      with:
        registry: gcr.io
        username: oauth2accesstoken
        password: ${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token }}


but i have not crated workload_identity_provider and authenticating using service account key
